# Calculation of data delta

Tags: math, interpolation, delta

I'm writing a server that sends a "coordinates buffer" of game objects to clients every 300ms. But I don't want to send the full data each time. For example, suppose I have an array with elements that change over time:

```
0  0 100 50 -100 -50   at time t  
0 10 100 51 -101 -50   at time t + 300ms
```

You can see that only the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, and 5<sup>th</sup> elements have changed.

What is the right way to send not all the elements, but only the delta?  Ideally I'd like a function that returns the complete data the first time and empty data when there are no changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to optimize for efficiency, or is this a learning exercise?  Some thoughts:

- Unless there's a *lot* of data, it's probably easiest, and not terribly inefficient, to send all the data each time.
- If you send deltas for all of the data points each time, you won't save much by sending zeroes for unchanged points instead of re-sending the previous vales.
- If you send data for only those points that change, you'll need to provide an index for each value.  For example, if point 3 increases by 5 and point 8 decreases by 2, then you might send `3 5 8 -2`.  But now, since you're sending *two* values for each point that changes, you'll only win if fewer than half the points change.
- If the values change relatively slowly, as compared to the rate at which you transmit updates, you might increase efficiency by transmitting the delta for each data point, but using only a few bits.  For example, with 4 bits you can transmit values from -8 to +7.  That would work as long as the deltas are never larger than that, or if it's ok to transmit several deltas before they "catch up" to the actual values.
- It may not be worthwhile to have 2 different mechanisms: one to send the initial values, and another to send deltas.  If you can tolerate the lag, it may make more sense to assume some constant initial value for every point, and then transmit only deltas.

Comment: It should be optimization in real project. I'm sending coords from football game. The number of clients is about 10k. So that why even a few bytes will optimize a lot.

Comment: How many coordinates are in the complete list?  There are many good ways to compress data, but in general it's best to get the code working and then benchmark it before you decide whether it's worthwhile to optimize.

Comment: So, worst case, you're transmitting just over 40 bytes.  The overhead for the ethernet and TCP headers is about 64 bytes, so there's no real advantage to compressing the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options.  If most data isn't changing, just send (index,value) pairs of the changed elements.  If most values change but the changes are small, compute deltas and gzip (or run length encode, or lots of other possibilities) the result.